# Why Post method of okhttp occur error [Content-Type header specified in HTTP request is not supported: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]?

Tags: android, salesforce

I call a Rest API of salesforce by post method:

```
url = "https://test-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountUsers/"
    client = OkHttpClient()
     val jsonIn = FormBody.Builder()              
            .add("email",URLEncoder.encode("dt1@gmail.com", "UTF-8"))
            .add("password", URLEncoder.encode("1","UTF-8"))
            .build()
    request = Request.Builder()
            .post(jsonIn)
           .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+accesstoken)
           .addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
           .url(url)
           .build()
        response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

This is rest api:

```
@HttpPost
    global static ID createUser(String email, String password) {      
        AccountUser__c us=new AccountUser__c();
        us.Email__c=email;
        us.Password__c=password;      
        us.Status__c=0;
        insert us;      
        return us.Id;
    }
```

But result return is error:

```
[{"errorCode":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"Content-Type header specified in HTTP request is not supported: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}]
```

I had try change `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` , but still can't resolve.

I try call a `Get` method, it is ok.

Why Post method occur error [Content-Type header specified in HTTP request is not supported]?

Comment: you have to  pass all data in encoded form. see this https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000977iIAA

Comment: i had using URLEncoder.encode to encode data input, but still occur error.

Comment: just display your body in log and check is in urlencoded format

Comment: yes, value of body: email =dt1%2540gmail.com , password=1

Comment: In urlencoded form there is value concate with & not ,

Comment: no, i using json.

Comment: once try in postman or any rest client you get  idea

Comment: Had you connect android to salesforce?

Comment: i try test at https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php, it is ok,  this is problem call from android.

Comment: can you post response from a rest client?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a better resolution. [Retrofit Library](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Even though it is not mandatory to use Retrofit, these are few eye catchy aspects which makes it reliable and handy in similar use case of yours.

### Why to use Retrofit?

- Type-safe REST Adapter that makes common networking tasks easy
- For `POST` operations, retrofit helps in assembling what needed to be submitted. Eg:-  Generating URL encoded form.
- Takes care of URL manipulation, requesting, loading, caching, threading, synchronization, sync/async calls
- Helps to generate URL using type-aware generated code tied to specific REST API
- Parsing `JSON` using `GSON`
- Retrofit is an API adapter wrapped over `OkHttp`

---

The problem that you are facing can be resolved using retrofit like this.

```
public interface APIConfiguration{

    @Headers({"Accept:application/json",
            "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user/registration")
    Observable<DataPojo> registrationAPI(@FieldMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> params);

}
```

> That's it, with few annotation the library takes care of `Form URL
>   Encoding` and related dependencies.

As it is inappropriate to start from corresponding `Retrofit` dependencies and sample code, you can go through [Reference One](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845) and [Reference Two](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding just checkout the difference the content type header  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.
The content "multipart/form-data" follows the rules of all multipart MIME data streams.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Also try your http request by setting your content type header as multipart/formdata.